# If $u_n= \int_1^ne^{-t^2}dt$, what can be said about $\sum u_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If

> $\displaystyle u_n= \int_1^ne^{-t^2}dt$ where $n=1,2,3...$

Then Which of the following is true

> $1)$ both the sequence $u_n$ and series $\sum u_n$ is convergent
>
> $2)$ both the sequence $u_n$ and series $\sum u_n$ is divergent
>
> $3)$ The sequence is convergent and $\sum u_n$ is divergent
>
> $4)$ $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}u_n=\frac{2}{e}$

The solution I tried - I know that $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2}=\sqrt  \pi$ ,but how to calculate the $u_2,u_3...$ I have no idea please help

Comment: how can i apply that theorem here?

Comment: If you know that $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ is finite, then you know if the $u_n$ converge.  If the $u_n$ converge to a non-zero value, then you know if the sum in divergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $u_n$ is convergent to $C=\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt$. Because of this, the series $\sum u_n$ is divergent.

No quantitative estimation is really needed, but if you want one

$$ u_n = C-\int_{n}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt = C-\frac{1}{2}\int_{n^2}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{e^t\sqrt{t}}\geq C-\frac{1}{2n}\int_{n^2}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{e^t}=C-\frac{1}{2ne^{n^2}}. $$

Comment: how $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$?

Comment: @TheStudent: Initially I incorrectly assumed the left endpoint of the integration range to be zero, now fixed.

Comment: i have seen some of your answers ,The magic of inequalities you use to solve question is something beyond my mind , But +1 for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **3).**

1. The sequence is convergent, because we have
   $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{1}^{n} e^{-t^2}\ dt\right) = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt = \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt\right) - \left(\int_{0}^{1} e^{t^2}\ dt\right)$$
   and the left hand integral is $\sqrt{\pi}$, while the right-hand one must be a finite value(*) because $t \mapsto e^{-t^2}$ has no singularities for any $t \in [0, 1]$. Hence the limit exists by virtue of this expression thus having a well-defined finite value.
2. The series is divergent. This follows from the fact the above limit is nonzero, as it is a basic theorem that a *necessary* (but *not* sufficient) condition for convergence of a series is that the sequence of terms involved must converge *to zero* at infinity. The fact the limit is nonzero, in turn, is because in
   $$\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}\ dt$$
   the integrand $t \mapsto e^{-t^2}$ is always positive in $[1, \infty)$ (and anywhere else, for that matter).

---

(*) For what it's worth, the exact value is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left(1 - \mathrm{erf}(1)\right) \approx 0.7468$ (though one might object this is a bit "circular" in a sense, but...).